# ec2 security group settings, sftp and port 80 settings

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, filezilla

I have a Linux based ec2 instance on aws with prepackaged Tomcat7 and so far I'm able to:
ssh into the instance from command line,
connect to the instance FileZilla,
sudo start/stop tomcat (tomcat is listening on port 80)
All development administration on the project happens on Ubuntu 10.10

Problems/questions are:

**FileZilla**: when I try upload a war file to webapps I get:

```
Error: /opt/tomcat7/webapps/my-fancy-app-0.1.war: open for write: permission denied
Error: File transfer failed
```

I've not added any users ( or ec2-user to be exact ) to any groups associated with Tomcat.

**Port 80**: how do enable outside access on port 80? 
I have just the default security group, have not added any custom settings. When I select HTTP from the 'Create a new rule' dropdown the default setting is 0.0.0.0/0 - is this the safe or correct setting? When I have Tomcat running with that rule applied and try to visit the url shown next Public DNS I get (503 error I believe): `Service Temporarily Unavailable`

Last but not least, what is an Elastic IP and what role does it play in the larger picture?

Any help whatsoever will be extremely appreciated. Hopefully I'll get through this and be able to put all this in a 'paint by numbers' kinda tutorial.

Comment: Clarification: You are not using the default default security group if you can ssh in to your instance.  By default, the default security group does not allow any connections to your instance, so at some point you added permissions for at least port 22.

Comment: ... hm, that's very interesting. I absolutely don't recall making that change.

Comment: It's possible that you were using some tool our UI that added port 22 for you.

Comment: If "cl" means the Amazon API tools command line programs, then they do not automatically modify any security groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FTP**: are you using the FileZilla server or do you mean that you're using the FileZilla client? In that second case what FTP server are you using. This is a permission problem and the user to authorise might depend on the username that you're using for FTP. For example with proftpd, I'm using a different unix user id (not even created, just using the number) for each FTP username.

**Port 80**: Yes, 0.0.0.0/0 means to open the port 80 to everyone and this is the correct setting (how safe depends on how you secured your system).

**Elastic IP** is a way to associate IP addresses to machines, if for any reason your EC2 server doesn't work any more and you prefer to start a new instance, you can within minutes, start the new instance and assign your same IP address to the new instance, all from AWS management console. **Even in a different availability zone.**

Comment: I've not taken any steps to secure the instance, any recommendations at this point?  Elastic IP - that's what I suspected :-)

Comment: you should post another question about that, but on serverfault.com, not on stackoverflow.com (but search first).

Comment: FTP - just the desktop client, did not set up a ftp server

Comment: about Port 80, or FileZilla or both?

Comment: @vector, ah so you're using ssh transfer with FileZilla? With which user? Try to add that user to tomcat group, but you've also to check that the war is group writeable. For the 2nd comment, I meant tips on how to secure your server, chances are that there will be already around.

Comment: yes, ssh, 'ec2-user', literally, I can ssh to the instance from command line with ec2-user@blah-blah... Tried adding the user to the tomcat group : useradd -G tomcat7 ec2-user ...and failed: -bash: useradd: command not found

Comment: try as root/sudu with usermod -a -G tomcat7 ec2-user -- if it fails try with whereis or locate to find it. or you can open /etc/group and do it yourself, but only if you understand what you're doing.

Comment: how do I make the war group writeable?

Comment: Got it! made webapps dir group writable: sudo chmod -R g+rwx webapps ... war getting transferred!